# Crystal Report doesn't display data in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, reportviewer

In my project, the Crystal report viewer doesn't display data the first time I click the display button.

When I close the crystal report viewer and press the display button again, it will show the data. Why does it work like this?

Comment: please saw your code.

Comment: the problem is not get value from one form to another. i checked with Messagebox. But not show any data as message.